# selectors in UL

Tags: menu, html-lists, css-selectors

I have a problem with a simple "ul" menu i have created. What i want to achieve is to simply add padding to menu items 1 - 4 and not the logo image. 
Ive tried a class on the "a" tags but no joy.
I can pad the whole UL selecting "ul.menu" which you would expect. (this all occurs with display:inline) If i float:left instead of display:inline i can select the "a" tags only but i am stuggling to center the entire menu with the header if i do this.

So what is the solution? I want to add a 100px padding-top to just the "a" tags not the logo image.

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper clearfix">

    <div id="header">

 <nav> 
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
      <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo">
      <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
    </ul> 

 </nav>     

    </div><!--end of header-->

  </div><!--end of wrapper-->
</body>
```

CSS

```
li {
display:inline;
padding-left: 2%;   
padding-right: 2%;
}

.wrapper {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%
}
#header {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
display: block;
background-image:url(../images/header.jpg);
font:"Agency FB";
}

#logo   {
padding-top: 1%;
padding-bottom: 1%; 
}
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Putting img tags in ul's is not valid HTML.
You have to wrap the img in a li tag first, and give it an ID, like so:

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Stuff</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Stuff2</a></li>
<li id="logo_li"><img src="myimage.jpg"></img></li>
</ul>
```

Then apply a CSS like this:

```css
ul li {
padding-top: 100px;
}
ul li#logo_li {
padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Here is a working example jsfiddle of what you want to achieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/4BjEz/
(added red borders so you can see the li's height+ padding)